# What can I do to stabilize my wifi connection?

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, realtek-wireless

Recently, I got a TP-LINK TL-WN823N Wireless-N USB adapter. It works perfectly fine on Windows, but on Ubuntu it's unstable. It often fails to connect and even when it connects it often fails on me. What's weird is that when it fails on me, rather than that blue thing popping up in the top right corner saying "Disconnected - You are now offline" It just continues to show that I'm connected. The way I notice that I'm actually disconnected is by clicking on something on a webpage and having my browser say "Unable to connect to the Internet". I tried solving the problem like this:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8192cu fwlps=0" > /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8192cu.conf
modprobe -r rtl8192cu
modprobe rtl8192cu
exit
sudo reboot
```

I think it may have helped a little, but it certainly didn't completely solve the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you have rtl8192cu? Please give output of `lsusb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a better driver by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms linux-firmware
```